# Make an element stick to the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following code produces a set of blue boxes and within two of these boxes a small white box is displayed. How can I make these white boxes stick to the bottom of the blue boxes? I tried to add `margin-top: auto;` to `.test` but that did not work.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.test {
    background-color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex 
  item 1<div class="test"></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2<div class="test"></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` to those `.test` cubes (you could also add `left: 0`, but that's the default anyway), and `position: relative;` to their containers to have them serve as an "anchor" for the absolute position of their children.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;;
}

.test {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Conterning the additional question in the comment:

You can define the flex items as flex containers with `flex-direction: column` and apply `margin-top: auto` to `.test`. However, you need to change the `height` of `flex-item` to `min-height` in order to allow it to expand:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. Could you also tell me how to make sure that when resizing the height of .test (for instance from 20px to 50px) that .flex-item resizes along with it such that the white box (.test) stays at the bottom and below the text and does not overlap the text above it?

Comment: That won't work - absolutetey positioned elements are independent from their parents, so changing their size won't affect any othe objects (and might overlap them).

Comment: Yeah I just tried it and noticed it. Is there a way to cope with this?

Comment: I just added a second solution, have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much Johannes for the clear solution and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your css and add `position: relative` to 'flex-item,
and `position: absolute` to 'test'.
Of course you have to add `bottom: 0px` to send it to the bottom

```
.flex-item {
  position: relative;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
background-color: white;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin` would work if **the parent is also a flexbox**  *(Also if there is **one** value for margin-x)*.

**here :** `margin:auto 0 0;` should do.

*(`margin:auto 0 0 auto ;`would set it at bottom right )*

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
        display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.test {
    background-color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex item 1flex 
  item 1<div class="test"></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2<div class="test"></div></div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) directly on a flex child.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.place-at-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}


/* ignore them */
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.place-at-bottom {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="place-at-bottom"></div>
</div>
```